# How to get custom SQLite DB table URI without using content provider?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursorloader

I want to load data from database while scrolling, so I am using loader callback. But in init loader it is asking for database URI. If I use a ContentProvider, then it is working fine. But I would like to initialize the loader without a ContentProvider.

Comment: You just asked this a few minutes ago, why did you ask it again?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a different Loader. I recommend copying the source of `CursorLoader` and changing it to use an instance of your database (more specifically, your subclass of `SQLiteOpenHelper`) instead of the Uri and other arguments it uses to talk to `ContentResolver`.